# JavaFX ComboBox background color per selected item

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, javafx-8

I would like to change background of a `ComboBox` based on selected item.

For example: if selected first item then background should be green, if second one is selected then red.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just set the color of the `ComboBox` itself and not the items of the `ComboBox` inside the drop-down list, you can create a custom binding between the [buttonCellProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#buttonCellProperty--)  and the [valueProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#valueProperty--) of the `ComboBox` to implement the custom coloring.

**Example**

This example colors the `ComboBox` to green if the first item is selected, to red if the second item is selected, and leaves the coloring as it is otherwise.

**Update:** The background color of the arrow button of the `ComboBox` is also colored now, for that the [lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) method can be used to get the arrow button: `StackPane arrowButton = (StackPane) combo.lookup(".arrow-button");`.

```
ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
combo.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"));

combo.buttonCellProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {

    int indexOf = combo.getItems().indexOf(combo.getValue());

    Color color = Color.TRANSPARENT;

    switch (indexOf) {
    case 0: color = Color.GREEN; break;
    case 1: color = Color.RED; break;
    default: break;
    }

    final Color finalColor = color;

    // Get the arrow button of the combo-box
    StackPane arrowButton = (StackPane) combo.lookup(".arrow-button");


    return new ListCell<String>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
                setText("");
            } else {
                setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(finalColor, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                setText(item);
            }

            // Set the background of the arrow also
            if (arrowButton != null)
                arrowButton.setBackground(getBackground());
        }

    };
}, combo.valueProperty()));
```

*The result is like:*

[image]

**Notes**

**1)** If you want to color the items also in the drop-down list, you can pick the solution from other answers here.

**2)** If you do not display `String`s but items that are able to store also the color of the item, the solution is even shorter, just use the color of the selected item in `updateItem` method rather than calculating your own color.

Comment: Works nice, but background of arrow button at right side is not colored.

Comment: Updated the answer for you to color the arrow button background also.

Comment: Thanks! That's great.

Answer (score 1):

Sure this is possible. Create custom `ListCell`s in a [`cellFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#cellFactoryProperty) you use with the `ComboBox` and use it to modify the `Cell`'s style based on the item it contains.

Example:

```
public class Item {

    public Item(String value, Color color) {
        this.value = value;
        this.color = color;
    }

    private final String value;
    private final Color color;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

```
ComboBox<Item> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Item("Summer", Color.RED),
        new Item("Winter", Color.CYAN),
        new Item("Spring", Color.LIME),
        new Item("Autumn", Color.BROWN)
));

comboBox.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Item>(){

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
            setText("");
        } else {
            setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(item.getColor(),
                                                            CornerRadii.EMPTY,
                                                            Insets.EMPTY)));
            setText(item.getValue());
        }
    }

});

comboBox.setButtonCell(comboBox.getCellFactory().call(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Main extends Application {

Random r = new Random();
private class Item {
    Color c;
    String s;
    public Item(Color a,String b){
        c = a;
        s = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return s;
    }
}

private void addAll(List<String> items){
    for(String s : items){
        box.getItems().add(new Item(Color.WHITE,s));
    }
}

ComboBox<Item> box;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Pane p;

    try {
        p = new StackPane();
        box = new ComboBox<Item>();
        box.setMinWidth(100);
        addAll(Font.getFontNames());
        box.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Item>, ListCell<Item>>() {

            @Override
            public ListCell<Item> call(ListView<Item> param) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return new ListCell<Item>(){


                    @Override
                    public void updateSelected(boolean selected) {
                        super.updateSelected(selected);
                        if(selected){
                            getItem().c = Color.rgb(r.nextInt(205),
                                    r.nextInt(205), r.nextInt(205), 1);

                        }
                        setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black; -fx-background-color: #" +
                                getItem().c.toString().substring(2)+";");
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if(empty){
                            return;
                        }
                        setText(item.toString());
                        setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black; -fx-background-color: #" +
                                getItem().c.toString().substring(2)+";");
                    }

                };
            }
        });
        p.getChildren().add(box);
        p.setPrefSize(500, 500);
        Scene scene = new Scene(p);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().
                getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    combobox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String t, String t1) {
            if (t1.equals("Option 1")) {
               combobox.setStyle(" -fx-background-color: #000000");
            }
            if (t1.equals("Option 2")) {
                combobox.setStyle(" -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF");
            }
        }
    });
```

you should be able to do something quite simple like the above with a basic change listener, you may have to refresh the page (I often just remove and re-add the component so you can see the change take place)

This is on the basis you want to select a combobox item then the box to change, not each item to have a different colour from the start